# Creating an image with Docker and resources outside the main directory

Tags: docker, image, dockerfile

I try to build an image with Docker (10.20.13 on RH 7.9). But some of my resources are outside the Dockerfile directory. Below is my tree :

```
/dir1
├── dir2
│   ├── dir3
│   │   ├── dir4
│   │   │   ├── boost
│   │   │   │   └── lib
│   │   │   │       ├── linuxV2_6_18A32
│   │   │   │       │   ├── libboost_atomic-mt.a
│   │   │   │       │   ├── ....

/home/myproject/myDockerfile
```

I want to add in my image the resources that are in `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/boost` which are not necessary my resources (but I do have at least read access).
My first try was to build an image from `/home/myproject/myDockerfile` with the following command :

```sh
/home/myproject/myDockerfile/docker build -t myimage:1.0 .
```

But it failed with, saying this:

```
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat dir1: file does not exist
```

Okay, the `dir1` is not in the context. So I tried to make a link to dir1 in the Dockerfile directory, and again the same command, but different issue :

```
ADD failed: forbidden path outside the build context: netdata ()
```

Third try, I launch the command from the root directory (to get all the context as I understand), with the following command:

```sh
docker build -t myimage:1.0 -f /home/myproject/myDockerfile
```

This time I get this response:

```
error checking context: 'no permission to read from '/boot/System.map-3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64''
```

So I image to add the last directory to my `.dockerignore`, but it should be in the context (root directory) which is impossible.

So is there a solution to my problem apart copying in project directory all the resources I need?

Comment: How you are executing your dockerfile means any pipeline or directly in linux terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy all of the resources you need into the project directory.  You can't really build a Docker image containing files from completely unrelated parts of the filesystem (you can't include a library from `/usr/lib` from a Dockerfile in your home directory).

Since what you're trying to include is a static library, you have a couple of options to get it.  The easiest is to just install it via your base image's package manager:

```sh
FROM debian:stable
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      libboost-atomic1.74-dev
```

A second harder option is to use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) or a similar technique to build the library from source.

Since the specific file you're referencing is a static library, another option could be to build the binary on the host system and `COPY` it into the image unmodified.  This requires you to be on a native-Linux host with a similar base Linux distribution.

```sh
FROM debian:stable
COPY ./myapp /usr/local/bin
CMD ["myapp"]
```

```sh
gcc -o myapp ... -lboost_atomic-mt
docker build -t myapp .
```

If all else fails then you can make a copy locally.  You might write a script to do this; this is also a place where Make works well since it's largely dealing with concrete files.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
mkdir ./docker
cp -a Dockerfile .dockerignore src ./docker
cp /dir1/dir2/.../libboost_atomic-mt.a ./docker
docker build -t myapp ./docker
```

Comment: It is what I did, but I do not like this solution. But if it is the only way. Thanks for the answer.